# How can I base64-encode an Image Transform?

Tags: assets, image-transforms, assetfilemodel

I'm trying to use [this plugin](https://github.com/radarseven/Craft-Twig-ImageBase64), but it requires an `AssetFileModel` as input. I can pass it the asset in question, no problem, but I'm wanting to pass it a transformed version of the asset. However, it seems like there's no way in Craft to pass a transformed image as an `AssetFileModel`.

Here's my code:

```
{% set image = assetField.first() %}

{# Doesn't work; `image.url({width: 40})` outputs a URL as a string, not an AssetFileModel #}
{% set imageTiny = image.url({ width: 40 }) | image64(true) %}

<div style="background: url({{ imageTiny }});">...</div>
```

The desired result is for a base64-encoded string of the tiny, 40px-wide image to be output in the HTML.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% set image = assetField.first().setTransform({width: 40}) %}
```

That should return an `AssetFileModel`, allowing you to do `{{ image64(image) }}`

If you need to reuse the image with other transforms later, you might have to do some magic / use different variables.

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to work with this particular plugin:

`` // Require an instance of `AssetFileModel`
        if (! $asset instanceof AssetFileModel)
        {
            // Die quietly.
            return false;
        } ``

It specifically checks the parameter that you pass in, and expects it to be an `AssetFileModel`. It wouldn't be too hard to modify the plugin to work for your use-case, though.

I see what you're trying to do; if you're using Craft 3, you could use the [ImageOptimize](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft3-imageoptimize) plugin to do it for you.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. So there's no way for Craft to return an `AssetFileModel` for an Image Transform, eh? I think there's a fork of the plug-in that might accept other parameter formats; I'll have to check that out.